Using y right axis axis - tikz
I asked this before but somene said it needed clarification. Sorry for the oversight,
I want to plot a stacked area. However, when trying to use the secondary y-axis, the "yticklabel" is not positioned correctly. For example, the number 10, 20, 30, are a little "shifted down" (the first blue block, for example, in the year 1990 is 8.3, but when defining the y-axis to the right it seems to be greater than 10). This does not happen if I use the y-axis on the left.
I would appreciate any comments.
My mwe:
\documentclass[letterpaper,12.0pt]{report}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
 
\begin{document}

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    width=16.0cm,
    height=0.45\textheight,
    area style,
    enlarge x limits=false,
    stack plots=y,
    grid=none,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=35,
    xmin=1989, 
    xmax=2023,
    symbolic x coords={1989,
                       1990, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99,
                       00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 
                       10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
                       20, 21, 2022, 2023},
    xtick=data,
    xtick={1990,95,00,05,10,15,2022},
    xticklabels={1990,95,00,05,10,15,2022},
    nodes near coords={},
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    xticklabel style={font=\footnotesize, black},  
    axis x line*=bottom,
    xtick style={draw=none},
    axis y line*=right,
    ylabel near ticks, 
    yticklabel pos=right, 
    y axis line style={draw opacity=0},
    yticklabels={},
    ytick={10,20,30},
    extra y ticks={10,20,30},
]

% Concentrates
 \addplot [draw=blue!75!white, fill=blue!75!white, opacity=0.70] coordinates
{(1990, 8.343) (91, 8.674) (92, 8.722) (93, 8.811) (94, 8.705) (95, 8.996) (96, 9.628) (97, 9.766) (98, 10.226) (99, 10.455) (00, 10.878) (01, 11.039) (02, 10.835) (03, 10.977) (04, 11.889) (05, 12.233) (06, 12.161) (07, 12.523) (08, 12.450) (09, 12.677) (10, 12.662) (11, 12.501) (12, 13.034) (13, 14.381) (14, 14.514) (15, 15.238) (16, 16.484) (17, 16.280) (18, 16.641) (19, 16.528) (20, 16.585) (21, 17.247) (2022, 17.618)} \closedcycle;

% SX/EW
 \addplot [draw=red!75!white, fill=red!75!white, opacity=0.70] coordinates
{(1990, 0.884) (91, 0.699) (92, 0.776) (93, 0.761) (94, 0.835) (95, 1.074) (96, 1.456) (97, 1.748) (98, 2.001) (99, 2.312) (00, 2.321) (01, 2.597) (02, 2.652) (03, 2.722) (04, 2.706) (05, 2.694) (06, 2.823) (07, 2.985) (08, 3.082) (09, 3.264) (10, 3.324) (11, 3.459) (12, 3.644) (13, 3.791) (14, 3.906) (15, 3.914) (16, 3.912) (17, 3.785) (18, 3.957) (19, 4.142) (20, 4.161) (21, 4.013) (2022, 4.303)}
\closedcycle;

% Direct melt
 \addplot [draw=yellow!60!white, fill=yellow!60!white, opacity=0.70] coordinates
{(1990, 3.547) (91, 3.557) (92, 3.740) (93, 3.876) (94, 4.422) (95, 4.892) (96, 4.866) (97, 5.082) (98, 4.828) (99, 4.650) (00, 5.269) (01, 4.766) (02, 5.009) (03, 4.803) (04, 5.117) (05, 5.188) (06, 5.470) (07, 5.662) (08, 5.412) (09, 4.683) (10, 5.104) (11, 5.327) (12, 5.321) (13, 5.434) (14, 5.674) (15, 5.629) (16, 5.715) (17, 6.005) (18, 6.251) (19, 6.136) (20, 5.973) (21, 6.332) (2022, 6.341)}
\closedcycle;

% Secondary refined
\addplot [draw=black!30!white, fill=black!30!white, opacity=0.70] coordinates
{(1990, 1.904) (91, 1.863) (92, 1.827) (93, 1.882) (94, 1.805) (95, 2.099) (96, 1.997) (97, 2.130) (98, 2.112) (99, 2.139) (00, 2.097) (01, 1.892) (02, 1.898) (03, 1.786) (04, 2.069) (05, 2.161) (06, 2.613) (07, 2.739) (08, 2.825) (09, 2.847) (10, 3.236) (11, 3.468) (12, 3.596) (13, 3.803) (14, 3.915) (15, 3.945) (16, 3.866) (17, 4.063) (18, 4.035) (19, 4.007) (20, 3.843) (21, 4.149) (2022, 4.153)}
\closedcycle;
\end{axis}
\node[black, font=\footnotesize, anchor=south] at (14.5, 9.1) {[Mt]};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Hm, you ask 2 questions: please remove one of them. This way we preserve 1Q=1problem, each answer=1solution. Thank you

Done, just one question: Why when using the y-axis on the right side the scale of the graph is lost and the stacked areas do not align with the y-axis marks.

That's probably just a visual effect:

switch on the grid, the reference you mention is fine
adding all last y-data is fine all the way up

So, nothing to solve here, besides may be the way of representing the data.

